# Не видит typedef из header файла

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Есть файл player.h:

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

/*-------------Libraries-------------*/
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "map.h"
#include "view.h"
/*-------------Libraries-------------*/

/*---------Typedef---------*/
typedef struct Player
{
    double x;
    double y;
    SDL_Texture *texture;
} Player;
/*---------Typedef---------*/

/*--------Func-Prototypes--------*/
void init_player
( 
    Player *player, Game_Map *game_map,
    char path[], SDL_Renderer *renderer
);
/*--------Func-Prototypes--------*/

#endif
```

Компилирую таким образом:

```
#!/bin/bash

gcc -Wall -o roguelite map.c view.c player.c main.c -lSDL2
```

Выкидывает ошибку:

```
In file included from view.h:9,
                 from map.h:10,
                 from map.c:1:
player.h:24:21: error: unknown type name ‘Game_Map’
   24 |     Player *player, Game_Map *game_map,
      |
```

Почему то не видет тип Game_Map в player.h, хотя перед прототипом функции есть #include "map.h"

map.h:

```
...
typedef struct
{
    int max_x;
    int max_y;
    char grid[ MAX_Y ][ MAX_X ];
    SDL_Texture *floor_texture;
    SDL_Texture *wall_texture;
} Game_Map;
...
```

... - другой код.

Если ошибка в том, как я использую #include, ссылка на github с проектом для полной картины:
https://github.com/Ilya-Piskurov/SDL_Roguelite/tree/develop

Comment: Решением оказалось размещения view.h ниже typedef, но вопрос есть ли решение красивее? Хочется чтобы все инклуды были в одном месте, или это нормально что не в одном?

Comment: Отправил тебе пул реквест для фикса.

Comment: https://github.com/Ilya-Piskurov/SDL_Roguelite/pulls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение очень просто, т.к. ты не используешь в заголовочных файлах никаких полей из структур, то тебе попросту не нужны включения звголовочных файлов в других звголовочных файлах.

Просто определи прототип структуры, и подключай заголовочные файлы только в исходных файлах.

E.G:

```
/* player.h */
...

typedef struct Game_map Game_map;

...

/* player.c */

#include "map.h"
...
```

Comment: Просто если я перестану использовать заголовочные файлы в других заголовочных файлах vs code перестанет понимать откуда я беру некоторые типы и константы, хоть и будет компилироваться.

Comment: А ему и не нужно об этом знать! Просто компилятору так даже будет легче собирать, с малым кол-вом включений.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что для структур размещать прототипы, а все включения делать только в .c файлах ?

Comment: Желательно, но не всегда это нужно, следите за тем используется ли у вас что-то важное из заголовочного файла в другом, и только тогда включайте его.

Answer (score 0):

Проследил путь, оказалось проблема при компиляции файла map.c, он тащил view.h до определения типа, и вызывал player.h из-за чего и была ошибка. Исправление:
поместить #include "view.h" после typedef